# IOS application change language with custom settings screen

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, multilingual

I developed multi language, navigation controller based application. The main menu of the application have also and settings screen at below. User can change to application language with language button pressed. I want to refresh main menu screen and also settings screen language When user changed language But i did not.

[image: settings screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nl" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSString *englishWord = @"translate";
NSString *translation = [bundle localizedStringForKey:englishWord value:englishWord table:nil];
NSLog(@"%@ = %@", englishWord, translation);
```

---

```
// nl.lproj/Localizable.strings:
"translate" = "vertaal"
```

Comment: This is work, Thanks basvk. But I used NSLocalizedString() method all localization titles. Can I change that you say?

Comment: Create a simple class which will be initialized with the proper language (@"nl", @"de", @"fr", etc) and another  method that returns the translated word. You've got to replace all of the `NSLocalizedString()` function calls with your new class. (find & replace)

Comment: Just what i need, thank you, simple and clear. For a strange reason our client is insisting on in-app language change, and that made me a lot of headaches

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that Apple discourages language selection in the app. The best solution is to just localize your Views and use NSLocalizableString, and just let the language in the app follow the language of the phone's settings.

Answer (score 0):

make a method (which returns a dictionary of language strings loaded from plist) in the AppDelegate.
Whenever user selects a language set the NSUserDefaults accordingly, and call that method in app delegate.
Now use this method in viewWillAppear of every controller and get the desired language dictionary and load your views.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*)getCurrentLanguageDictionaryFromResource
{
    NSString *defaultPath;
    defaultPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",[self getAppCurrentSettingsLanguage]] ofType:nil];
    if(languageDictionary !=nil)
    {
        [languageDictionary release];
        languageDictionary=nil;
    }
    languageDictionary  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:defaultPath];


    return languageDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart application, if you want to change language.

For this, you can use local notifications to again restart your application with proper message showing user that your application will get re-started now.

Hope this description helps you......

Comment: That's not true.
Just use a different `NSBundle`, no need to restart (and I highly discourage that).